# Notice: Undefined offset: 1, 2, 3, 4 in dynamic_arr()

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, undefined, offset

I'm getting these errors on my following lines:

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 at 
`$dynamic_arr[$key][trim($tt[1])] = array(`

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 at 
`'type'  => trim($tt[2]),`

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 at 
`'size'  => trim($tt[3]),`

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 at 
`'widget'  => trim($tt[4]),`

I'm not getting basically whats the issue here?

```
<?php
foreach($b_csv as $key = > $csv) {
  $dynamic_arr[$key] = array();
  $aa = explode("\n", $csv);
  foreach($aa as $key2 = > $value) {
    $tt = explode(',', $value);
    if (isset($tt)) {
      if (!empty($tt[5])) {
        $dynamic_arr[$key][trim($tt[1])] = array(
            'label' = > trim($tt[0]), 
            'type' = > trim($tt[2]), 
            'size' = > trim($tt[3]), 
            'widget' = > trim($tt[4]), 
            'option' = > trim($tt[5]),
        );
      } else {
        $dynamic_arr[$key][trim($tt[1])] = array(
            'label' = > trim($tt[0]), 
            'type' = > trim($tt[2]), 
            'size' = > trim($tt[3]), 
            'widget' = > trim($tt[4]),
          );
      }
    }
  }
}
return $dynamic_arr;
?>
```

Comment: Provide example input for `$b_csv`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (isset($tt))
```

to:

```
if (!empty($tt))
```

`$tt` will always be set, because you just assigned it on the previous line. But if it's empty, you'll get errors in the `else` block because you'll try to access elements of the array.